# How can I set my cell width in React-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I almost use the same code as the DOCS, but when I set the width in the columns, nothing, what's going on? I just want to set width /maxwidth for my cell

here is what I changed

```
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Requests',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'Data1',
            accessor: 'Data1',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Data2',
            accessor: 'Data2',
            width:10
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the columns array directly without using useMemo and you can set the width for each column.

Comment: Can you share the react component where you are going to use this columns array?